# What are the requirements for the TrueCrypt privilege escalation?

Tags: truecrypt, privilege-escalation, veracrypt

The details on the [TrueCrypt 7.1a (and by extension the CipherShed and VeraCrypt v1.15 and older) privilege escalation vulnerability](http://www.ethical-hacking.it/truecrypt-security-history-from-istruecryptauditedyet-to-oct-2015/) [CVE-2015-7358](https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/133878/Truecrypt-7-Derived-Code-Windows-Drive-Letter-Symbolic-Link-Creation-Privilege-Escalation.html) are available now, including a proof-of-concept implementation of the exploit.

Now, as I don't really understand what is going on there I'd like to know who has to worry about this.

Does there need to be TrueCrypt *installed* onto the machine? Does the executing user needs administrator privileges to obtain system privileges via the exploit? Can one exploit this on a mobile basis with the traveller installation of TrueCrypt?

Answer (score 1):

The vulnerability exists in a situation where you have TrueCrypt or one of it's forks on a computer that is a "shared" machine. For example, imagine you as Alice installed TrueCrypt 7.1a on a supported Windows Server, created a TrueCrypt volume, and then mounted it. Bob, as another user on the same server could potentially inspect the configuration of that volume and/or manipulate that volume's drive letter. It does not appear that the unencrypted contents of the volume would be directly exposed by the vulnerability. I agree with the person that reported the issue that if you are mounting TrueCrypt volumes on a shared system with other users currently logged on (or really any un-trusted process running), you have other problems to be concerned with.

For more information see https://code.google.com/p/google-security-research/issues/detail?id=537

Comment: As an aside, I found in interesting to see that there is apparent animosity between the developers of VeraCrypt and CipherShed as denoted by the comments for that particular issue as it was reported.

Comment: I *think* this is not CVE-2015-7358. I *think* this is [CVE-2015-7359](https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/133877/Truecrypt-7-Privilege-Escalation.html). CVE-2015-7358 is categorized to be more critical and explicitely mentions *"it's trivial to get a new process running under the local system account"*. At Google, this is [issue 538](https://code.google.com/p/google-security-research/issues/detail?id=538).